# Java UDP Server, concurrent clients

Tags: java, sockets, udp

Is the code below sufficient to accept concurrent UDP transmissions? More specifically, if 2 clients transmit concurrently, will DatagramSocket queue up the transmissions and deliver them one by one as I call receive(), or will only one make it through?

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port, address);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

while(!disconnect){

    DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    socket.receive(p);
}
```

Comment: Note: UDP doesn't support connections.  You have individual packets flying around.

Comment: Edited to make it a little clearer. Thanks.

Comment: if you want to make sure to receive packets from two clients, create two sockets, each receiving on a different ports. are you restricted to have only one socket?

Comment: It's a server, it's supposed to serve an unspecified number of clients on a specific ip address/port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no queuing by default. The client may retry till timeout or similiar are reach.
UDP is quiet fast but on heavy load you may have clients that cannot connect.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid missed connections? Even if I were to create multiple DatagramSockets, they can't have identical ip/port pairs can they?

Comment: in the UDP protocol, there are no connection, just packets as Peter mentioned already.

Comment: I understand, I'm using the word connection/transmission interchangeably. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid dropping packets due to only having one DatagramSocket.

Comment: @Justin984 Think of UDP as shouting for someone across a noisy room, and TCP as making a phone call. UDP just sends data to a given socket without the overhead of making a connection. It has no idea if the server heard it, or even exists. UDP is useful for real-time applications like VoIP that are subject to the [cliff effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliff_effect), where some data loss is inconsequential. It sounds like you want TCP.

Answer (score 0):

If the packets make it to your networking interface (imagine lost packets on a congested wireless channel) they will passed up and the blocking method `socket.receive(p)` will be called. If there is a collision of packets on the channel because of two clients transmitting at the same time you will not get any of the two packets. But this is most likely not possible because the access technology of networking interfaces will take care of this, check
[CSMA/CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_avoidance) or [CSMA/CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_detection)

After calling `socket.receive(p)` you should create a new thread to process the packet itself. That will make sure that the next packet can be received on the socket.

**EDIT:**
[Description of INTEL's TX and RX descriptors](http://communities.intel.com/community/wired/blog/2011/06/24/parameter-talk-tx-and-rx-descriptors)

Comment: I am wondering more about what happens when two clients connect to the same destination ip address/port but different ephemeral source ports. Assuming no physical or data later collision, what would happen if client one sends a packet triggering receive() to unblock, and then client 2 sends just before I call receive again. If there is no queuing behind the scenes, then the packet is lost.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but the networking interface, or even the system networking stack will take care of that and the situation that you are not able (not fast enough) to call `receive()` again is very unlikely. Just process the packet in a new thread to run into another loop of `receive()`.

Comment: I don't think it's that unlikely under high load.

Comment: As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) stated about UDP:  _there is no guarantee of delivery, ordering or duplicate protection._

Comment: I understand that there is no delivery guaranteed by the protocol. But if the packet has made it to the system, the protocol is over. We are now talking about how Java handles getting those packets to my code. In the case I outlined, under heavy load, I will lose packets.

Comment: Depends on definition of heavy load. Anyways, after receiving the packet on the networking interface you have more layers between the air interface and the java virtual machine, means the operating system and the network card driver which handle the packets and can hold more than one packet a time as I found in an article of INTEL where the networking card supports about 2048 TX descriptors. Please find the link in my updated post :)

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution would have on thread responsible for handling a number of incoming requests (with your desired limit) and then handing them off to other worker/request handler threads. This basic structure is very much the same with most servers: a main thread responsible for handing off requests to worker threads. When each of these worker threads is finished, the you can update a shared/global counter to let the main thread know that it can establish a new connection. This will require synchronization, but it's a neat and simple abstraction.

Here's the idea:

**Server Thread**:

```
// Receive Packet
while (true) {
    serverLock.acquire();

    try {
        if (numberOfRequests < MAX_REQUESTS) {
            packet = socket.receive();
            numberOfRequests++;
            requestThread(packet).run();
        } else {
            serverMonitor.wait(serverLock);
        }
    } finally {
        serverLock.release();
    }
}
```

**Request Thread**:

```
// Handle Packet
serverLock.acquire();

try {
    if (numberOfRequests == MAX_REQUESTS){         
        numberOfRequests--;
        serverMonitor.pulse();
    }
} finally {
    serverLock.release();
}
```

This is just to give you an idea of what you can start out with. But when you get the hang of it, you'll be able to make optimizations and enhancements to make sure the synchronization is all correct.

One particular enhancement, which also lends itself to limited number of requests, is something called a [ThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).