# How to avoid dropped packets with concurrent UDP server

Tags: java, sockets, udp

[Here is the original link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516734/java-udp-server-concurrent-clients) that spawned this question.

So, apparently DataGramSocket will not queue received packets. So if two systems send concurrently, one of the packets will get lost (using the code from the link). I'm looking for ways to avoid dropping packets in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are queues but they are always limited and you can always reach the limit.  There is no way to avoid such issue completely.  You can minimise the impact by having a low load on your servers so it can drain the queues quickly, and a dedicated network for UDP traffic.

Generally you have to build in some allowance for lost packets and you have to make the protocol reliable.

Comment: When you say "there are queues", do you mean that DataGramSocket queues received packets? For example, if I call receive(), and another packets comes in before my code can loop around and call receive() again, will that packet be queued and returned the next time I call receive or will it get dropped?

Comment: I mean the routers, the network adapter and the OS has buffers or queues.  Java doesn't have an additional queue if that is what you mean.

Comment: Even if you are draining one packet at a time, very fast and doing nothing else, you can have packets dropped by any component along the way.  The buffers in various devices buffer all packets so if you have a busy TCP connection, expect UDP packet loss even if it is very light. There are other packet types like ICMP and all these compete for space in the various buffers in your network.

Comment: Right, I understand that. But it seems to me that if the packet gets to my system, then I should be able to read it, UDP has done its job at that point. I'm not trying to avoid all the networking issues, I'm simply wondering how I can restructure my code to account for the packets lost in this specific case. Could I possibly have a pool of DataGramSockets and call receive() on all of them so one will pick up the packets that the other may have missed. I don't know, that's what I'm asking :)

Comment: Until you have the packet read it, there is no guarantee of delivery.  This will be determined by whether a buffer is filled or in your OS or network adapter. The only solution is to read the data as fast as possible to avoid buffers filling up stream. e.g. you can have one thread to nothing but read packets and add them to a queue.  Of course you risk filling the memory of your JVM, or losing packets during a GC, but that is usually larger and easier to manage. You have to remember that no matter what you do in Java or any other language, packet loss is always possible.

Comment: My application functions fine with packet loss. I just don't see any reason to simply ignore packets that made it to my system but were dropped because I called receive() at the wrong time. It seems like a better design would be for DataGramSocket to queue the messages so I receive them the next time i call receive(). The general consensus seems to be to just ignore them, so I guess I'll move on! Thanks for your input.

Comment: DatagramSocket cannot queue packets which were dropped before you received them.  Packets are queued already, the problem is that these queues are limited in size and have to share with other traffic.  If you want to queue packets yourself, you can but this has only limited effect because there isn't much to you do to reduce the queues of systems you have no control over.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure no data (packet) gets lost use TCP!

An advantage of UDP is that is has less overhead and is thus used for congested, high traffic connections, like video or game streams. A reason for the lower overhead is the lack of guarantees about data not getting missing during the transmission.

From your question is seems that you do care about missing data, so you need to build in measures to detect this. If you do you probably want the data to be resend until it arrived properly? This is what TCP offers you..!

If it is really Java that is dropping the data it is probably due to queues being full. The UDP protocol might be 'over', but Java knows there is a UDP protocol with all of its 'consequences'. As UDP is designed for high-throughput, the Java parts are designed for the same requirement. Queuing *everything* causes (massive) overhead which contrary to the UDP design, so this is highly unlikely. Furthermore, dropping data from a queue is nothing different than losing data during transmission (IMHO), so it does not surprise me that Java drops data!

If you want to prevent this you need bigger queues (although the might fill as well) and more importantly faster handling of the queued data (to prevent filling the queues).

But the *most important* thing to do is to accept data loss! If your application/server cannot handle this: do *not use UDP*

Comment: I agree that TCP is likely to be the solution in most cases.

Comment: I am building a TCP server alongside the UDP server. However, this is not an issue with UDP. It is a problem with Java failing to queue received packets. If the packets got there, then the protocol worked just fine, so why are they dropped?

Comment: I updated my answer with some of my additional thoughts on the subject. Note: your really need to *stop calling the data packets*! It is your first wrong assumption leading to all of these questions...

Comment: If you have packet loss, it is highly unlikely that Java is the cause of your problem. (unless you are seeing significant packet loss over loopback)

Comment: @Veger while TCP has streams and any underlying packets used are not meaningful.  UDP does have packets of data and generally the packets you send is how they arrive. Possibly not in the same order or complete or not at all but a high percentage of packets will have the length you gave them when they were sent.