# How many requests can a java UDP socket handle?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, udp

I need to build a UDP server which can handle ~10_000 requests/sec. Started with below code, to test whether a java socket can handle those number of requests.

I am bombarding the server for a minute with ~9000 requests,

```
Total number of requests sent from the client : 596951
```

and in the tcp dump I see

```
90640 packets captured
175182 packets received by filter
84542 packets dropped by kernel
```

UDP Server code :

```
try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port)) {
            System.out.println("Udp Server started at port :" + port);


            while (true) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket incomingDatagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                try {
                    socket.receive(incomingDatagramPacket);
                    LinkedTransferQueue.add(incomingDatagramPacket);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    continue;

                }


            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

> What is the the probable cause kernel dropping the packets in program
>   this simple ?
>
> How to reduce it ? Any other implementation ?

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517579/how-to-avoid-dropped-packets-with-concurrent-udp-server), reading from the comments,lose of packets for UDP protocol can always happen even between network to java socket.recieve method.

Note: Have to figure out regarding anomalies in the tcpdump packets captured, but there is quite number of packets dropped.

*The anomalies in the tcpdump is the [lack of buffer space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144794/why-would-the-kernel-drop-packets), In order to know the number of packets received , I am using the [iptraf-ng](http://iptraf.seul.org/2.6/manual.html) which gives the number of packets received per port :)*

Comment: The probable cause is the socket receive buffer filling up, due to not reading it fast enough. Try it wth fewer `println()` calls, e.g. one per hundred datagrams.

Comment: @EJP I have done that, but still there is packet loss

Comment: Use Multithreading, to handle multiple packets simultaneously. You may also activate the flow-control on your Ethernet interface and on the corresponding port on your switch (but loosing packets is a way to be informed of a congestion, so activating flow-control may have bad side effects).

Comment: EJP is most likely right. Did you try increasing the udp socket buffer? In linux: sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=26214400

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo , Any example of handling packets multithreaded ?

Comment: @Andy I will try with increasing the udp socket buffer size as u said.

Comment: @Andy still i could see packets are dropped but atleast it has lower a bit.

Comment: In my current tests datagram socket can handle as many 40000 req/sec with about 13% packet loss with (packet size of ~1000 Bytes), and "sat -n UDP" will give you the number of requests received per second and number of packets lost per second, i have  no clue why I have started using iptraf-ng command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mutli-threading**

Your code sample does nothing after the a packet is received. If that is the case, multi-threading cant help you.

However if that's just for testing and your actual application needs to do something with the received packet, you need to push the packet to another `Thread` (or a pool of them) and go immediately back to listening for the next packet.

Basically you need to minimize the time between two calls of the `socket.receive()`.

*Note: this is **not** the only mutli-threading model available for this case.*

**Buffer size**

Increase the buffer size with `socket.setReceiveBufferSize` which maps to the SO_RCVBUF:

> Increasing SO_RCVBUF may allow the network implementation to buffer multiple packets when packets arrive faster than are being received using receive(DatagramPacket).

However, this is just a **hint**:

> The SO_RCVBUF option is used by the the network implementation as a **hint** to size the underlying network I/O buffers.

You could also, if your setup allows it, go directly to the OS and change the size of the buffer.

**Irrelevant**

*Note: Read this only if you are not sure that the packet size is less than 1024 bytes.*

Your packet buffer size seems low for generic packets, which can lead to bugs because: If a packet is larger than your buffer there will be no error, it will just ignore the overflowing bytes.

EDIT:

**Other Multi-threading model**

*Note: This is an idea, I don't know if it actually works.*

3 Threads:

- Thread A: handling packets
- Thread B1: receive packets
- Thread B2: receive packets

Init:

- Atomic counter set to 0
- B1 is receiving, B2 is waiting.

While loop of the B1:

- while counter > 0 wait
- counter += 1
- received the packet
- counter -= 1
- wake up the B2
- push the packet to A's queue

Same for B2.

This the threads diagram (line where the packet has been received):

```
B1 [--------|---]    [--------|---]
B2          [--------|---]    [--------|---]
```

Comment: I have updated the code, I have changed the os buffer size  as suggested in the comments, still there is packet loss of 10% :(

Comment: Have you tried other machines? There is also the possibility that the network card is the bottleneck and you cant improve it...

Comment: I added an other multi-threading model if you are interesting, its just an idea I you are desperate you can test it... no promises

Comment: @ManooAK actually I have tried withe same idea previous day, more than 2 threads, I will update the code later, Figured out with threads packet loss is more, :(. I came to conclusion that the bottle neck is the "socket.receive", and copying in to buffer. even if you increase the number of threads, it will be still the same. I am gonna try with nginx udp load balancing instead to reduce the packet loss.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using threads, can you check the possibility of using NIO2 APIs here by using AsynchronousDatagramChannel.

Help link: 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-nio2-1/index.html

Comment: AsynchronousDatagramChannel class was removed from the java 8 http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6993126

Comment: @forum.test17 That's not correct, and it's not what the bug report says. It was *withdrawn* from Java 7 before it was ever released, and it is now present in Java 8. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

The actual number of packets what can be handled depends on CPU of your and target server, the network connection between them and your actual program. If you need a high performance solution for networking in Java you can use coral reactor: http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/the-simplicity-of-coralreactor/

Answer (score 0):

One disadvantage of UDP is it does not come with the reliable delivery guarantees provided by TCP
The UDP protocol's **mcast_recv_buf_size** and **ucast_recv_buf_size** configuration attributes are used to specify the amount of receive buffer.

It Depends upon the OS you are using to run your program. Buffer size for different OS are :

```html
<table sytle="width:100% border:1px solid black">
<tr>
<th><b>Operating System</b></th> 
<th><b>Default Max UDP Buffer (in bytes)</b></th>
</tr>
<tr><td>Linux</td>                     <td>131071</td></tr>
<tr><td>Windows</td>          <td>No known limit</td></tr>
<tr><td>Solaris</td>                     <td>262144</td></tr>
<tr><td>FreeBSD</td>             <td>262144</td></tr>
<tr><td>AIX</td>                     <td>1048576</td></tr>
</table>
```

So UDP load handling depends upon machine as well as OS configuration.