# How to create a simple java load balancer with sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

Running a UDP Sever listening to multiple ports as simple as this

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
executorService.execute(new UDPServer(9998));
executorService.execute(new UDPServer(9999));
// UDP server implementation
try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port)) {
    System.out.println("Plain UDP server :" + this.port + " name :" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    int numberOfPacketsReceived = 0;
    while (true) {
        // todo check to stop the server
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket incomingDatagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        try {
            socket.receive(incomingDatagramPacket);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + numberOfPacketsReceived++);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue;
        }
    }
} catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can we create a load balancer programatically listening to the port
 9997 and forwarding the packet to port 9999/9998 alternatively ?

Can we even redirect the traffic received in one UDP socket to another
 another socket ?

Comment: What's stopping you from trying? Start a server on 9997, then send every 2nd packet to 9999 instead of 9998.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off having the workers take from a blocking queue, and having a third thread that just read in packets and put them on the queue for computing the values.

You could redirect the packets to another socket, but this would have unnecessary overhead within the same program, and you would lose the packet metadata.

If you wish to use a load balancer you could implement the load balancer like this:

```
class C {
  public static void main(final String... args) {
    try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(9997);
         DatagramSocket out = new DatagramSocket()) {

      final InetSocketAddress[] sockets = {
          new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9998),
          new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9999)
      };

      int i = 0;
      while (true) {
      // todo check to stop the server
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket incomingDatagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        try {
          socket.receive(incomingDatagramPacket);
          incomingDatagramPacket.setSocketAddress(sockets[i++%2]);
          out.send(incomingDatagramPacket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          continue;
        }
      }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear if OP wants to run the balancer and workers separately or on the same machine. For a single machine it is a decent answer though.

Comment: @forum.test17 I would advise you to profile your code and share the results in a separate question on SO if it's not clear how to act upon them. Load balancers are usually used to split traffic between different machines, i. e. when one machine is clearly not enough.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 i will do that in this thread soon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023098/how-many-requests-can-a-java-udp-socket-handle

Comment: Added a way to implement the desired behaviour

Comment: You don't need three sockets for this, and you aren't redirecting anything here, just sending packets back to the same port they came from.

Comment: I tested it locally and it seemed to work, the destination address is changed, I only see 2 sockets, although one could be reused instead

Comment: My code was based on [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html)

Comment: @EJP could you explain the issues you got running my code, it seemed to work, I ran 2 UDP listeners with nc on port 9998 and 9999 and connected in on port 9997 with nc, and my inputs went to the correct server instances